# Linode: SSH shows only welcome message

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, linode

After logging into the remote server, only the following welcome message is shown. **I'm unable to cd into the required directory.**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.6.5-x86_64-linode71 x86_64)
Puppet environment: my-environment
Vendor: linode
OS version: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Last login: Mon Oct 24 00:39:38 2016 from 14.142.150.35
```

**What have I tried?**
I tried connecting via Filezilla and I'm able to connect and access the files in the remote server.

**Relevant question in StackOverflow:**
[ssh hangs on “Last login” line](https://serverfault.com/questions/317890/ssh-hangs-on-last-login-line) - Couldn't find a solution from this question.

Kindly note that I'm fairly new to Linux. Your solution is much appreciated.

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the server doesn't support SSH. So using a SFTP client solves the issue.

If you're looking to connect to remote server via SFTP from Ubuntu, then this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/349879/593022) works fine.